# A query I'm doing on MySQL takes over 51 hours to complete

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance

The structure of the query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field from table where (param1 IS NULL OR param1=CURDATE()) and (param2 IS NULL or param2=CURDATE())
```

There are no indexes on param1 or param2.  We have a lot of data, and I want to have a cron job run a script that runs this query on a daily basis.

Suggestions?  Should I somehow split this into multiple smaller queries?

**EDIT: I'm expecting around 10 million results.**

Comment: "no indexes" - "lot of data" - there's your problem.  Having dates in where clauses probably invalidates the index even if you add one.

Comment: @duffymo I don't understand your reference to invalidation.

Comment: "WHERE param1 = curdate()" means you have to scan each and every row, regardless of index.  You ought to find somebody who actually knows something about relational databases, SQL, and MySQL to help you.  Start by running EXPLAIN PLAN on your query.  If you see TABLE SCAN come back you should redesign it.

Comment: ...but curdate()  in not a function applied  to a column  ..is a matching value   so .. the index  . is used if exist .. and for this the value of curdate in select is evaluated  at the begin of the query code  analisys by the sql engine ..

Comment: Anyway  if the OP show use the actula data schema wn can eval if index  are present or not ???

Comment: How big is your table and how many results do you expect? Unless your table contains terrabytes of data (which is doubtful if the database still runs without indexes), it is unlikely that a simple full table scan (even with distinct ordering) will take 51 hours. Maybe your query is locked by some other query, crashed or something similar. Try restarting it (although adding indexes should of course make it faster).

Comment: Are there any reasons you can't use indexes? param1/param2 look like fields with high selectivity and indexes would be helpful

Comment: I'm not the database administrator.  I'm a developer and maybe I can make some requests, but this is a long-time existing database (over a decade?), and I'm just supposed to do read-only queries on it

The number of results might be in the range of ~10 million

Comment: Contact the database administrator and request it be indexed, or that they dig into why the queries are so slow.

Comment: How many rows in the table currently?  `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.  Also, let's see the schema: `SLOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this index is likely to help:

```
INDEX(param1, param2, field)
```

(It would help to know the size of the table, the schema, etc)